# Is there any way to count the production of specific rules in order in a context free grammar?

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar, context-free-grammar, regular-language, context-free-language

Is there any way to use a counter in context-free grammars?

I need to add a module number (for example starting from `M1:0, M1:1, ... , M1:K` representing the module number) and I want to count every block productions in order. The following production rule just adds an arbitrary `digit` number from `<digit_list>`:

```
S ⇒ <block> <fblock> <fcblock>  
<block> ⇒ <cblocks><pblock>  
<cblock> ⇒ <Module_ID>:<digit_list><cblock>|<Module_ID>:<digit_list><cblock><cblock>|<Module_ID>:<digit_list><cblock><cblock><cblock>  
<cblock> ⇒ [C<block>]
<bblock> ⇒ BN|λ 
<pblock> ⇒ <Module_ID>:<digit_list>[P<dblock>] |λ 
<dblock> ⇒ D|λ   
<fblock> ⇒ <Module_ID>:<digit_list>[F]
<fcblock>⇒ <Module_ID>:<digit_list>[FC<UNIT><dblock>]|λ 
<UNIT> ⇒ 64|128
<Module_ID> ⇒ M1
<digit_list>⇒ <digit>|<digit><digit_list>
<digit>⇒ 0|1|2|...|9
```

Is there any way to generate and count the modules number produced on **the right-hand side** of the production rules (the modules that have `<Module_ID>:<digit_list>` before) that I need to count them?

Is there any example or resources that I can use and refer to them?

**Edited:**

For example, the following shows the generated string I need to add `M1:0` and etc before the modules in bracket `[]` to count them:

```
M1:0[CBN][CBN][C]M1:1[PD]M1:2[F]M1:3[FC64D]
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I fully grasp what you're trying to do, but it doesn't sound like something you can do that with just a context free grammar. By definition, a CFG has only a finite number of symbols and rules. So you'd have to implement it yourself, either during the parse using whatever action framework your parser generator provides, or after the parse is finished by walking the parse tree (or AST, if applicable).

Comment: @rici thanks for your comment. May I know what do you mean by AST?

Comment: AST is short for Abstract Syntax Tree and is used to present a given instance of source code in the form of a tree where the nodes correspond to symbols in your grammar. Module ID value can be considered a property of symbol `<Module_ID>` and be assigned during the parsing process. For example, page 2 of https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs143/cs143.1128/handouts/160%20Syntax-Directed%20Translation.pdf shows a tree with attributes in nodes.

Comment: So, module ID can be kept track of, but you cannot achieve it merely by a grammar. Tools such as `bison` allow you to provide rules to control the parsing when a node expands (i.e. a symbol on the left hand side of a production is to be replaced by the right-hand-side symbols). You can set a global counter, increment and assign its value to `<Module_ID>` every time a new module is found.

Comment: @SimonSmith Thank you for your comment. I am not really familiar with the concept of attributed nodes. But I found this (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220743149_Context-aware_mutation_a_modular_context_aware_mutation_operator_for_genetic_programming) which I am not sure how much relates to my problem. what do you think?

Comment: @S.EB I don't think the material is related to your problem... I suggest reading the dragon book (_Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools_). Chapter 2 provides an overall introduction of Syntax-Directed Translation, and after reading it you will see how attributes can be associated with symbols. There's a link: https://repository.unikom.ac.id/48769/1/Compilers%20-%20Principles%2C%20Techniques%2C%20and%20Tools%20%282006%29.pdf

Comment: @SimonSmith Thank you very much for your help and comments. May I know is there any python tool that is being used to implement CFG with Syntax Directed Translation?Or is there any practical examples available?